# Is there any way to schedule batch script to run for X hours continuously?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a power shell script which will create some workload and am calling that script as logon using batch script, i dont know some how it is running for 10 mint only, with out completion batch script got stopped. How can i schedule the batch script like it should run for 1hr or what ever i want ?
 Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you call the powershell script inside the batch script, please show it?

Comment: @echo off powershell -command "& { C:\workload.ps1 }" >> Z:\output_workload
pause